# Store key & value in other array in php

Tags: php, arrays

How to take the keys and values ​​of a array after having positioned to a known key ?

**My array :**

```
[Bolivia] => a
[Brazil] => v
[Belgium] => d
[Cuba] => c
[Croatia] => x
[Finland] => j
[Germany] => m
[India] => n
[Japan] => w
```

**Know key :** [`Croatia`]

**The search result :**

```
[Finland] => j
[Germany] => m
[India] => n
[Japan] => w
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it like this:

```
$known_key = 'Croatia';
$input = [....];

$result = [];
$passed = false;
foreach($input as $key => $value){
    if($passed){
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }

    if($key == $known_key){
        $passed = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_slice to get it.

```
<?php
$array = array(
'Bolivia' => 'a',
'Brazil' => 'v',
'Belgium' => 'd',
'Cuba' => 'c',
'Croatia' => 'x',
'Finland' => 'j',
'Germany' => 'm',
'India' => 'n',
'Japan' => 'w');

$keys = array_keys($array);
$keys_flip = array_flip($keys);
var_dump(array_slice($array, $keys_flip['Croatia'] + 1));
```

output:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
array(4) {
  ["Finland"]=>
  string(1) "j"
  ["Germany"]=>
  string(1) "m"
  ["India"]=>
  string(1) "n"
  ["Japan"]=>
  string(1) "w"
}
```